# Vuex state is sometimes empty (undefined), especially when I refresh the page and sometimes it works

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, store

Vuex state is sometimes empty (undefined), especially when I refresh the page. And sometimes it works.

**action:**

```js
getSkills(context) {
  let url = "/skills";
  const headers = {
    "x-api-key": process.env.VUE_APP_SIRH_X_API_KEY,
    Authorization: localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
  };
  return axios({
    method: "get",
    url: url,
    headers: headers,
  }).then((response) => {
    context.commit("getSkill", response.data.data.skills);
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
},
```

**getter:**

```js
Skills: (state) => state.Skills,
```

**mutation :**

```js
getSkill(state, skills) {
  state.Skills = skills;
},
```

**state :**

```js
Skills: [],
```

and the **vue** :

```js
computed: {
  ...mapState({}),
  ...mapGetters(["Candidate", "Skills"])
},
mounted() {
  this.getSkills();
  this.id = this.$route.params.id;
  this.Skills.forEach(element => this.skill_list.push(element.skill_name));
},
methods: {
  ...mapActions(["attachSkillCandidate", "getSkills"]),
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getSkills` action is performing an *asynchronous* request. You need to wait for the request to finish before you can access `this.Skills` otherwise the data will not be set yet.

You need `async` and `await` (the "modern" solution):

```js
async mounted() {
  await this.getSkils();
  this.id = this.$route.params.id;
  this.Skills.forEach(element => this.skill_list.push(element.skill_name));
}
```

or:

```js
mounted() {
  this.getSkils().then(() => {
    this.id = this.$route.params.id;
    this.Skills.forEach(element => this.skill_list.push(element.skill_name));
  });
}
```